# List comprehension using index values

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

How do I turn the below for loop into a list comprehension?

I have a list of lists. Each sublist has a number in index 4 position, and I would like to find a way to add them up. The for loop works, but I'd like a one-line solution with list comprehension.

```
frequencies = []

for row in table:
    frequencies.append(int(row[4]))
sum(frequencies)
```

Here's my attempt:

```
frequencies = [sum(i) for i, x in enumerate(table) if x == 4]
```

However, the result is an empty object.

```
In[52]: total
Out[52]: []
```

Comment: The list comprehension is _totally_ different to the first version. Don't you just want `[int(row[4]) for row in table]`?

Comment: "add them up"? Your first snippet that you say works does not "add up" anything, but collects them.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the adding line (edited).

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I presume OP intended `... if i == 4]`, i.e. use the enumerate'd index to filter out just the 4th column. But they'd also need `for i, x in enumerate(row) for row in table if i == 4]`. Agreed it's unnecessarily redundant when we can simply slice `row[4]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it like this -

```
frequencies = sum([int(row[4]) for row in table])
```

The approach you're using is a little different from what you want to achieve.

Comment: Nice, but "one-line solution" requested, so `sum([int(row[4]) for row in table])`. /s

Comment: `sum` accepts any iterable, so `[`....`]` is unneeded. `sum(int(row[4]) for row in table)` is both more legible and probably (veeeery slightly) more performant (as a list does not need to be allocated).

Comment: @Amadan That slight performance improvement would be 0.001 microsecond.

Comment: @ShreyanAvigyan It's not just CPU performance but also memory too.

Comment: @TuanChau Python doesn't eat memory because of reference counting. Memory is not a factor here. Though it's the user's choice what the user wants to do.

Comment: @ShreyanAvigyan, Sure. The discussion here is not related to the original problem but about the improvement of your solution (your code is closest to what the author want, I must say that). In most cases, we don't need to care much about the performance, especially memory. Both with and without `[]` have the same bigO (O(n)) but without `[]`, we just use O(1) space.